# How do I make yahoo unblock the images that come with the emails coming from our server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I make yahoo unblock the images that come with the emails coming from our server?

Comment: you're gonna need to explain what you mean a little better.  Is this even a programming question or are you trying to figure out how yahoo mail works?

Comment: we've been sending invites out.. now the problem is that users of yahoo mail don't seem to have the images..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [HTML email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_e-mail), which is a wild beast at the best of times, you should be using some kind of starting template before embarking on any sort of customization. There are a number of examples out there that are excellent reference but Campaign Monitor has made a serious effort to promote best practices.

- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/

It may be helpful to use an email previewing service like Litmus to verify your messages are being transmitted as intended:

- http://litmusapp.com/email-testing

Answer (score 0):

Is it all yahoo users or just some?  Many users turn off images in email for privacy reasons (to prevent companies from using image requests as a confirmation that someone got an email.)